# SafeArgs and Navigation Component to open url android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-safe-args

I'm currently want to open url if it's clicked when i'm passing data using navigation component, and its ben a few days since i'm trying to fix it and i don't know where is wrong with my code

the second fragment called fragment_barang cannot be clicked and i even use webview as a catalyst to open the web, can you guys help me with this?

this is fragment_barang

```
package rizkyfadilah.binar.synrgy6.android.challengechapter3

import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import rizkyfadilah.binar.synrgy6.android.challengechapter3.databinding.FragmentBarangBinding

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 * Use the [fragment_barang.newInstance] factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
class fragment_barang : Fragment() {
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null
    private var _binding: FragmentBarangBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }



    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentBarangBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val barang1 =  arguments?.getString(Fragment_Abjad.EXTRA_BARANG1)
        val barang2 =arguments?.getString(Fragment_Abjad.EXTRA_BARANG2)
        val barang3 = arguments?.getString(Fragment_Abjad.EXTRA_BARANG3)
        val abjad = arguments?.getString(Fragment_Abjad.HURUF)
        val toolbar = view.findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.t_toolbar_barang)

        toolbar.apply {
            title="Word Start With $abjad"
        }

        val listbarang = arrayListOf(
            barang(barang1 = "$barang1"),
            barang(barang1 ="$barang2"),
            barang(barang1 = "$barang3")
        )
        val rv_barang = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv_barang)
        rv_barang.apply {
            layoutManager =LinearLayoutManager(activity)
            adapter = listadapterbarang(listbarang)

        }

    }


    companion object {
        val EXTRA_LINK = "EXTRA_LINK"
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment fragment_barang.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            fragment_barang().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }

}
```

this is webfragment

```
package rizkyfadilah.binar.synrgy6.android.challengechapter3

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 * Use the [webfragment.newInstance] factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
class webfragment : Fragment() {
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_webfragment,container,false)
        val webview = view.findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView)
        webview.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        webview.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        val url = arguments?.getString("url")
        if (!url.isNullOrBlank()){

            webview.loadUrl(url)

        }
        return view

    }


    companion object {
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment webfragment.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            webfragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

this is main_navigation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragment_Abjad">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_Abjad"
        android:name="rizkyfadilah.binar.synrgy6.android.challengechapter3.Fragment_Abjad"
        android:label="fragment__abjad"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment__abjad" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragment_Abjad_to_fragment_barang"
            app:destination="@id/fragment_barang" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragment_Abjad_to_fragment_barang2"
            app:destination="@id/fragment_barang" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_barang"
        android:name="rizkyfadilah.binar.synrgy6.android.challengechapter3.fragment_barang"
        android:label="fragment_barang"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_barang" >
        <argument
            android:name="barang1"
            app:argType="string"
            android:defaultValue="Kosong" />
        <argument android:name="barang2"
            app:argType="string"
            android:defaultValue="Kosong" />
        <argument
            android:name="barang3"
            app:argType="string"
            android:defaultValue="Kosong" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragment_barang_to_webFragment"
            app:destination="@id/webFragment" />

    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/webFragment"
        android:name="rizkyfadilah.binar.synrgy6.android.challengechapter3.webfragment"
        android:label="Web Fragment"
        android:layout = "@layout/fragment_webfragment">
        <argument
            android:name="url"
            app:argType="string" />
    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

and this is the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".fragment_barang">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:id="@+id/t_toolbar_barang"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/rv_barang"
        />



</FrameLayout>
```